# Regex pattern in JavaScript to test for dots/hyphens in names

Tags: kosaraju-algorithm

Required regex pettern like

1. allow only letters with  min 1 dot and maximum 3 dots.
2. allow optional as '-' special character.

Ex: raj.gopal-reddy  or raj.reddy.gopal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site is not a free code writing service, where you tell us what to write, and then we go off and write the code for you.  You are expected to always show _some_ effort when you ask a question.  If you get downvoted, then consider including your current effort to reverse that trend.

Comment: i am using below regex pattern to allow dots min 1 and max 3 and there is no other characters except letters    /^(?!.*?\.\.)(?:[a-zA-Z]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]+)\.*[a-zA-Z]+\.*[a-zA-Z]+?$/i;

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current attempt. A block formatting tool is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex is on the right track, and I would use a negative lookahead to assert that more than three dots do not occur.  Consider this pattern:

```
^(?!.*\..*\..*\..*\.)[A-Za-z-]*\.[A-Za-z-]*$
```